# Confused with Bootstrap Internet Explorer 10 in Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Hope someone can help me understand this. Referring to this page on bootstrap. http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-ie10-width

Do I need to add this in my CSS?

```
@-webkit-viewport   { width: device-width; }
@-moz-viewport      { width: device-width; }
@-ms-viewport       { width: device-width; }
@-o-viewport        { width: device-width; }
@viewport           { width: device-width; }
```

and this in my JS?

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/)) {
  var msViewportStyle = document.createElement('style')
  msViewportStyle.appendChild(
  document.createTextNode(
  '@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important}'
 )
)
document.querySelector('head').appendChild(msViewportStyle)
}
```

Any example would be much appreciated.

Comment: "Do I need to add this in my CSS? and this in my JS?" The answer to both questions is: Yes.

Answer (score 0):

The following information is in the link you posted:

> As a heads up, we include this in all of Bootstrap's documentation and
>   examples as a demonstration.

It is a demonstration and so it is not included in Bootstrap itself, you have to add it yourself.

**EDIT**

As an example, you can just add the code at the end of the `<body>` or in the `<head>` like so:

```
<script>
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/)) {
        var msViewportStyle = document.createElement('style')
        msViewportStyle.appendChild(
                document.createTextNode(
                        '@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important}'
                )
        )
        document.querySelector('head').appendChild(msViewportStyle)
    }
</script>
```

and make sure you've added the CSS to your CSS file or as style in the `<head>`

Comment: Thanks and sorry for being a pain here. If it is need, why didn't Bootstrap add them by default. LOL, I know you don't work for bootstrap but I just want to know the logic on why they choose to get you to add them on your own. Thanks

Comment: I actually don't know, they should add it as default. Maybe they found this after their release and add this in their next release?