# Where to write Bootstrap options for ms viewport?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, cross-browser, internet-explorer-10

I am working on an web application which uses Bootstrap UI.
However other browsers looks fine, but in IE version 10, the UI looks broken.

I found a solution on the bootstrap official site.
It suggested something like below:

Put this on your CSS and JS.

CSS:

```
@-ms-viewport       { width: device-width; }
@-webkit-viewport   { width: device-width; }
@-moz-viewport      { width: device-width; }
@-ms-viewport       { width: device-width; }
@-o-viewport        { width: device-width; }
@viewport           { width: device-width; }
```

JS

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/)) {
    var msViewportStyle = document.createElement('style')
    msViewportStyle.appendChild(
        document.createTextNode(
            '@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important}'
        )
    )
    document.querySelector('head').appendChild(msViewportStyle)
}
```

So here is what I have done: I copied that CSS to `your_style.css` which is located under the `css` folder => this did not work and I got no idea where to insert this JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

here is a question/answer with explicit instructions

[Confused with Bootstrap Internet Explorer 10 in Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936666/confused-with-bootstrap-internet-explorer-10-in-windows-8-and-windows-phone-8)

One thing I would suggest though, is make sure compatibility mode isn't enabled in ie10..
I have had issues with this in the past.

Compatibility mode toggle, is highlighted in this image :

[image]